# PHPexcel export what are the best ways to handle large export

Tags: php

Currently I am working on survey related application where the number of participant and number of survey it will vary depends on the organization.

As of now I am doing export through the browsers. Currently the participant and survey data are less so the export works fine. But when the application grows bigger based on the server and php setting it will export or it will hang still.

Please let me know the best possible ways to handle this kind of scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips:

1. You can try to do the export in a cronjob, so you don't have any limits on browser timeout.
2. Increase the memory and execution time in php.ini (or by ini_set)
3. Make use of caching tables, first collect data and put them in a temp/caching table. Where the structure of the table is close the structure of the excel. So you have only receive the data from the temp/caching table and write them to a excel